# Issue regarding generate a complex sql : SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

i am in situation where i need to form a complex sql to show calendar like interface with datagridview in winform apps. i have done the job writing code in form. now i want to form the calendar at database level with sql. this is my UI look like
[image]

so what i am doing....i am generating a datatable first and adding column as per no of days in moth of year. in picture there is two dropdown from where user select month and year.

this way i am getting total no of days in moth of selected year.

```
TotalDays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(int.Parse(ddlYear.Text), DateTime.ParseExact(ddlMonth.Text, "MMMM", 
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month);
```

now i am adding column to datatable dynamically where two column is fixed called specialist id and name. here is the code which i am using to populate data table first.

```
DataTable dtHrs = new DataTable();
dtHrs.Columns.Add("SpecialistID");
                dtHrs.Columns.Add("SpecialistName");
                TotalDays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(int.Parse(ddlYear.Text), DateTime.ParseExact(ddlMonth.Text, "MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month);
                for (int i = 1; i <= TotalDays; i++)
                {
                    dtHrs.Columns.Add(i.ToString());
                }

                ds = Common.GetDataSet("select distinct SpecialistID,Name from specialists Where IsActive=1 and IsSpecialist=1 and IsExcluded=0 order by SpecialistID", "");
                if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                        {
                            dr = dtHrs.NewRow();
                            dr[0] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
                            dr[1] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString();

                            for (int y = 2; y <= dtHrs.Columns.Count - 1; y++)
                            {
                                dr[y] = "8.00";
                            }
                            dtHrs.Rows.Add(dr);
                        }
                    }
                }

Common.GetDataSet() return data as per sql.
```

the above code will populate specialist id and name and cell value as default `"8.00"`

making cell color red when day is `saturday and sunday` by the below code

```
        for (int y = 0; y <= dgView.Rows.Count - 1; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 2; x <= dtHrs.Columns.Count - 1; x++)
            {
                strDate = (dtHrs.Columns[x].ColumnName.ToString().Length > 1 ? dtHrs.Columns[x].ColumnName.ToString() : "0" + dtHrs.Columns[x].ColumnName.ToString()) + "/" + (DateTime.ParseExact(ddlMonth.Text, "MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month > 9 ? DateTime.ParseExact(ddlMonth.Text, "MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month.ToString() : "0" + DateTime.ParseExact(ddlMonth.Text, "MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month.ToString()) + "/" + ddlYear.Text;
                //IFormatProvider culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", true);
                strDayName = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dddd");
                if (strDayName.ToUpper() == "SATURDAY" || strDayName.ToUpper() == "SUNDAY")
                {
                    dgView[x, y].Value = "S";
                    dgView.Rows[y].Cells[x].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }
            }
        }
```

next again i am fetching specialist data saved in other table called `HourSheet`
and re-populate day cell again like below code

```
strSql = "select h.SpecialistID,s.Name,h.EntryDate,h.HoursData,h.Col,h.Row from HourSheet h,Specialists s ";
                strSql = strSql + "Where h.SpecialistID=s.SpecialistID and s.IsActive=1 and s.IsSpecialist=1 and s.IsExcluded=0";
                strSql = strSql + " and Month(EntryDate)=" + DateTime.ParseExact(ddlMonth.Text, "MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month + " and Year(EntryDate)=" + ddlYear.Text;
                strSql = strSql + " order by h.SpecialistID,Day(EntryDate),Month(EntryDate),Year(EntryDate) ";

                ds = Common.GetDataSet(strSql, "");
                if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        for (int y = 0; y <= dgView.Rows.Count - 1; y++)
                        {
                            for (int z = 0; z <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; z++)
                            {
                                if (dgView[1, y].Value.ToString().ToUpper() == ds.Tables[0].Rows[z]["Name"].ToString().ToUpper())
                                {
                                    dgView[int.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[z]["Col"].ToString()), y].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[z]["HoursData"].ToString();
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
```

here i gave all my c# code by which i populate grid and now i am asked to get the calendar like output at database level. i am not very good in db sql. so anyone would discuss what sql i need to write in sql server store procedure to get the output like above image. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would firstly recommend that you stop using the ANSI 89 implicit join syntax, in favour of the newer ANSI 92 explicit join syntax. The syntax you are using was replaced over 20 years ago. Some pretty compelling reasons for making the switch are [documented here](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). SO instead of:

```
SELECT  ...
FROM HourSheet h,Specialists s;
WHERE h.SpecialistID=s.SpecialistID
```

You would have:

```
SELECT  ...
FROM    HourSheet AS h
        INNER JOIN Specialist AS s
            ON s.SpecialistID = h.SpecialistID
```

I would secondly insist that you start using parameterised queries! Even though your input is controlled by the drop down box, so you are not actually vulnerable to malformed sql, or malicious sql injection, you are still forcing recompilation of your query every time since you cannot make use of cached plans. SO instead of:

```
strSql = strSql + " and Year(EntryDate)=" + ddlYear.Text;
```

You would simply use

```
strSql = strSql + " and Year(EntryDate) = @Year";
```

Then you could add the parameter to your SQL Command something like:

```
SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Year", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Int.Parse(ddlYear.Text);
```

Better still, you can avoid having to call functions on `EntryDate` in your query, and just get a date range for your query, so get the date/time from your drop down lists:

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(Int.Parse(ddlYear.Text, DateTime.ParseExact(ddlMonth.Text, "MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month, 1);
```

Then pass this date to your query:

```
WHERE EntryDate >= @Date
AND EntryDate < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @Date);
```

This now makes your query [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

Lastly, doing this in the database I would simply make your query return 31 for all days, then simply strip out columns in the application. This is much easier than working with a dynamic number of columns.

To transform your data to days I would use the [`PIVOT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) function, so with the changes described above your SQL would end up as:

```
WITH DataToPivot AS
(   SELECT  s.Name, 
            DayNumber = DATEPART(DAY, h.EntryDate),
            h.HoursData
    FROM    HourSheet AS h
            INNER JOIN Specialist AS s
                ON s.SpecialistID = h.SpecialistID
    WHERE   h.EntryDate >= @Date
    AND     h.EntryDate < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @Date)
    AND     s.IsActive = 1 
    AND     s.IsSpecialist = 1 
    AND     s.IsExcluded = 0
)
SELECT  pvt.*
FROM    DataToPivot AS d
        PIVOT
        (   SUM(HoursData)
            FOR DayNumber IN 
            (   [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], 
                [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], 
                [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31]
            ) 
        ) AS pvt;
```

Then all you need to do is modify your function `Common.GetDataSet()` to accept SqlParameters, so that you can send parameterised queries to the database.

**EDIT**

Based on the comment about missing data you are right, you would need to switch from `INNER` to `LEFT JOIN`, but you would also need to rearrange your tables, and your filters slightly:

```
WITH DataToPivot AS
(   SELECT  s.SpecialistID,
            s.Name, 
            DayNumber = DATEPART(DAY, h.EntryDate),
            h.HoursData
    FROM    Specialist AS s
            LEFT JOIN HourSheet AS h
                ON h.SpecialistID = s.SpecialistID
                AND h.EntryDate >= @Date
                AND h.EntryDate < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @Date)
    WHERE   s.IsActive = 1 
    AND     s.IsSpecialist = 1 
    AND     s.IsExcluded = 0
)
SELECT  pvt.*
FROM    DataToPivot AS d
        PIVOT
        (   SUM(HoursData)
            FOR DayNumber IN 
            (   [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], 
                [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], 
                [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31]
            ) 
        ) AS pvt
ORDER BY pvt.SpecialistID;
```

---

**EDIT 2**

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;

WITH DataToPivot AS
(   SELECT  s.SpecialistID,
            s.Name, 
            DayNumber = DATEPART(DAY, h.EntryDate),
            HoursData = CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, h.EntryDate) IN (6, 7) THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), 'S')
                            WHEN h.HoursData IS NULL THEN '8.00'
                            ELSE h.HoursData
                        END
    FROM    Specialist AS s
            LEFT JOIN HourSheet AS h
                ON h.SpecialistID = s.SpecialistID
                AND h.EntryDate >= @Date
                AND h.EntryDate < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @Date)
    WHERE   s.IsActive = 1 
    AND     s.IsSpecialist = 1 
    AND     s.IsExcluded = 0
)
SELECT  pvt.SpecialistID,
        pvt.Name,
        [1] = ISNULL(pvt.[1], '8.00'),
        [2] = ISNULL(pvt.[2], '8.00'),
        [3] = ISNULL(pvt.[3], '8.00'),
        [4] = ISNULL(pvt.[4], '8.00'),
        [5] = ISNULL(pvt.[5], '8.00'),
        [6] = ISNULL(pvt.[6], '8.00'),
        [7] = ISNULL(pvt.[7], '8.00'),
        [8] = ISNULL(pvt.[8], '8.00'),
        [9] = ISNULL(pvt.[9], '8.00'),
        [10] = ISNULL(pvt.[10], '8.00'),
        [11] = ISNULL(pvt.[11], '8.00'),
        [12] = ISNULL(pvt.[12], '8.00'),
        [13] = ISNULL(pvt.[13], '8.00'),
        [14] = ISNULL(pvt.[14], '8.00'),
        [15] = ISNULL(pvt.[15], '8.00'),
        [16] = ISNULL(pvt.[16], '8.00'),
        [17] = ISNULL(pvt.[17], '8.00'),
        [18] = ISNULL(pvt.[18], '8.00'),
        [19] = ISNULL(pvt.[19], '8.00'),
        [20] = ISNULL(pvt.[20], '8.00'),
        [21] = ISNULL(pvt.[21], '8.00'),
        [22] = ISNULL(pvt.[22], '8.00'),
        [23] = ISNULL(pvt.[23], '8.00'),
        [24] = ISNULL(pvt.[24], '8.00'),
        [25] = ISNULL(pvt.[25], '8.00'),
        [26] = ISNULL(pvt.[26], '8.00'),
        [27] = ISNULL(pvt.[27], '8.00'),
        [28] = ISNULL(pvt.[28], '8.00'),
        [29] = ISNULL(pvt.[29], '8.00'),
        [30] = ISNULL(pvt.[30], '8.00'),
        [31] = ISNULL(pvt.[31], '8.00')
FROM    DataToPivot AS d
        PIVOT
        (   SUM(HoursData)
            FOR DayNumber IN 
            (   [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], 
                [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], 
                [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31]
            ) 
        ) AS pvt
ORDER BY pvt.SpecialistID;
```

**EDIT 3**

In order to generate data where non exists in HourSheet (e.g. for the weekend you will need to generate a list of dates for your month, then you can left join to this. To generate the list I am simply using a table valued constructor:

```
SELECT N = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t1.N) - 1
FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) t1 (N)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1)) t2 (N)
```

This simply generates 32 rows (8x4), then gives each row an incrementing number using RowNumber. This number can be added to your start date to get a list of dates, and finally you can use calculate the number of days in the month using `(DATEDIFF(DAY, @Date, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @Date)))`, and use `TOP` to only return this number of rows:

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = '20150201';
SELECT  TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @Date, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @Date))) 
        Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY T1.n) - 1, @Date)
FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) t1 (N)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1)) t2 (N);
```

So your final query would be:

```
WITH Dates AS
(   SELECT  TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @Date, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @Date))) 
            Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY T1.n) - 1, @Date)
    FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) t1 (N)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1)) t2 (N);
), DataToPivot AS
(   SELECT  s.SpecialistID,
            s.Name, 
            DayNumber = DATEPART(DAY, d.Date),
            HoursData = CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, d.Date) IN (6, 7) THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), 'S')
                            WHEN h.HoursData IS NULL THEN '8.00'
                            ELSE h.HoursData
                        END
    FROM    Dates AS d
            CROSS JOIN Specialist AS s
            LEFT JOIN HourSheet AS h
                ON h.SpecialistID = s.SpecialistID
                AND CAST(h.EntryDate AS DATE) = d.Date
    WHERE   s.IsActive = 1 
    AND     s.IsSpecialist = 1 
    AND     s.IsExcluded = 0
)
SELECT  pvt.SpecialistID,
        pvt.Name,
        [1] = ISNULL(pvt.[1], '8.00'),
        [2] = ISNULL(pvt.[2], '8.00'),
        [3] = ISNULL(pvt.[3], '8.00'),
        [4] = ISNULL(pvt.[4], '8.00'),
        [5] = ISNULL(pvt.[5], '8.00'),
        [6] = ISNULL(pvt.[6], '8.00'),
        [7] = ISNULL(pvt.[7], '8.00'),
        [8] = ISNULL(pvt.[8], '8.00'),
        [9] = ISNULL(pvt.[9], '8.00'),
        [10] = ISNULL(pvt.[10], '8.00'),
        [11] = ISNULL(pvt.[11], '8.00'),
        [12] = ISNULL(pvt.[12], '8.00'),
        [13] = ISNULL(pvt.[13], '8.00'),
        [14] = ISNULL(pvt.[14], '8.00'),
        [15] = ISNULL(pvt.[15], '8.00'),
        [16] = ISNULL(pvt.[16], '8.00'),
        [17] = ISNULL(pvt.[17], '8.00'),
        [18] = ISNULL(pvt.[18], '8.00'),
        [19] = ISNULL(pvt.[19], '8.00'),
        [20] = ISNULL(pvt.[20], '8.00'),
        [21] = ISNULL(pvt.[21], '8.00'),
        [22] = ISNULL(pvt.[22], '8.00'),
        [23] = ISNULL(pvt.[23], '8.00'),
        [24] = ISNULL(pvt.[24], '8.00'),
        [25] = ISNULL(pvt.[25], '8.00'),
        [26] = ISNULL(pvt.[26], '8.00'),
        [27] = ISNULL(pvt.[27], '8.00'),
        [28] = ISNULL(pvt.[28], '8.00'),
        [29] = ISNULL(pvt.[29], '8.00'),
        [30] = ISNULL(pvt.[30], '8.00'),
        [31] = ISNULL(pvt.[31], '8.00')
FROM    DataToPivot AS d
        PIVOT
        (   SUM(HoursData)
            FOR DayNumber IN 
            (   [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], 
                [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], 
                [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31]
            ) 
        ) AS pvt
ORDER BY pvt.SpecialistID;
```

Comment: i guess join should be left outer join because HourSheet may not have data as per condition some time but Specialist always have data.

Comment: thanks but not being able to use order by clause like  ' order by SpecialistID,Day(EntryDate),Month(EntryDate),Year(EntryDate) '

Comment: Since you are only showing one month of data, ordering by month and year is pointless, they will all be the same. Similarly, ordering by Day won't achieve anything since you want this in columns not rows. I have added Specialist ID to the query, so that you are able to sort the pivot result by SpecialistID.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. one small issue that i want to show `8.00` when HoursData is NULL but if the day is `Sunday or Saturday ` then i want to show `S`. what to change please guide. thanks

Comment: I have added a second edit that does what you require. The problem is it requires mixing data types, and also mixing in business logic with your data. This could be better handled in your application rather than in SQL

Comment: thanks i have seen your second edit but there is one thing is missing that `S` is not showing for sunday and saturday.